# Table of contents to refer to runners in addition to or instead of pages

Tags: table-of-contents, books

I am using the class `jurabook` and I want to change the behavior of the table of contents.  `jurabook` offers the possibility of having runners that number the paragraphs.  These runners offer a more specific reference than pages.

I would like the table of contents to show the references to the runners instead of the pages or even better in addition to the reference to the pages.  Is it possible to change the behavior of the table of contents accordingly?

Here is a minimal example of a document using jurabook and runners.

```
\documentclass[compact,a5paper,12pt]{jurabook}
\usepackage[a5paper, left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm, top=2cm, bottom=1.5cm]{geometry}

\newcommand{\lorem}{\rn{Lorem} ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.

}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Chapter}
\section{Test}
\lorem
\lorem
\section{Test 2}
\lorem
\lorem
\lorem
\section{Test 3}
\lorem
\lorem
\section{Test 4}
\lorem
\lorem
\end{document}
```

---

Edit:

Thank you very much for your answer. It works within the minimal example. But I have problems applying it to a broader scale.

If I include the hyperref package, the solution does not work.  I am getting errors on typesetting.

And if I want some indication of which number is which, the text runs out of the page. For example using the code:

```
\def\addcontentsline#1#2#3{%
  \addtocontents{#1}{%
     \protect\contentsline{#2}{#3}{page \thepage\ (runner \the\numexpr\value{runner}+1\relax)}}}%
```

Comment: According to [jurabook.cls](http://mirrors.med.harvard.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/juramisc/jurabook.cls), that feature has been considered, but has not yet been implemented by the author of the class file. Search for "rnintoc" in the file: *Sollen auch die Randnummern in das Inhaltsverzeichnis mit aufgenommen werden? (funktioniert noch nicht!)* In English: *Should the runners also be included in the table of contents? (doesn't work yet!)* You will have to implement the feature yourself or wait for a proper answer to your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way of doing it.

Caution: one weakness of the solution is that, even if a section contains no `\rn`, it will still be associated (in the toc) to a runner value corresponding to that of the preceding `\rn` plus 1.

[image]

```
\documentclass[compact,a5paper,12pt]{jurabook}
\usepackage[a5paper, left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm, top=2cm, bottom=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{titletoc}

\newcounter{runnerplusone}

\renewcommand\addcontentsline[3]{%
    \setcounter{runnerplusone}{\value{runner}}%
    \addtocounter{runnerplusone}{1}%
    \addtocontents{#1}{%
    \protect\contentsline{#2}{#3}{\thepage\ (\therunnerplusone)}}}


\newcommand{\lorem}{\rn{Lorem} ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr,
sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat,
sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet
clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod
tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At
vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren,
no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Chapter}
\section{Test}
\lorem
\lorem 
\section{Test 2}
\lorem
\lorem
\lorem
\section{Test 3}
\lorem
\lorem
\section{Test 4}
\lorem
\lorem
\end{document}
```

---

An alternative (proposed by David Carlisle) using etex arithmetic to avoid allocating a new counter is

```
\def\addcontentsline#1#2#3{%
  \addtocontents{#1}{%
     \protect\contentsline{#2}{#3}{\thepage\ (\the\numexpr\value{runner}+1\relax)}}}
```

EDIT: the solutions above break if `hyperref` is loaded. To circumvent the problem, egreg proposed the following:

```
\documentclass[compact,a5paper,12pt]{jurabook}
\usepackage[a5paper, left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm, top=2cm, bottom=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\xpatchcmd\addcontentsline{\thepage}{\thepage\ (\the\numexpr\value{runner}+1\relax)}{}{}

\newcommand{\lorem}{\rn{Lorem} ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr,
sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat,
sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet
clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod
tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At
vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren,
no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Chapter}
\section{Test}
\lorem
\lorem 
\section{Test 2}
\lorem
\lorem
\lorem
\section{Test 3}
\lorem
\lorem
\section{Test 4}
\lorem
\lorem
\end{document}
```

Comment: you just beat me:-) But I posted mine anyway as I think you want to evaluate runner earlier, the write is a delayed write so that you get the correct page number.. ooh no protected@write does that I'll delete...

Comment: @DavidCarlisle That was a close race :) but I think that your solution was more elegant and that you should undelete it.

Comment: well it had a pointless expansion step, I deleted that bit and added it to the end of your answer, no need for two answers here really.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.  It works within the minimal example.  But I have problems applying it to a broader scale.  Using the `hyperref` package, I get an error on typesetting.  And if I want some indication of which number is which, the text runs out of the page.  For example using the following line `\protect\contentsline{#2}{#3}{page \thepage\ (runner \the\numexpr\value{runner}+1\relax)}}}`

Comment: To give more visibility to those issues you're having, you should uncheck my answer for the time being, and update your question (write about the new issues after "EDIT:" at the end of your question).

Comment: @Jubobs Using `\patchcmd` avoids problems: `\usepackage{xpatch}` and, after having loaded `hyperref`, do `\xpatchcmd\addcontentsline{\thepage}{\thepage\ (\the\numexpr\value{runner}+1\relax)}{}{}`

Comment: @egreg That's great! However, I'm reluctant to get credit for your solution. Don't you want to make it a full-blown answer of your own?

Comment: @Jubobs It's just a refinement of yours. Go ahead.